# deferring JavaScript execution in document received via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving this HTML document via AJAX:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="admin.php?do=media&action=file-upload">

    <div id="uploadForm">

        <div id="fileList">



        </div>

        <a href="#" id="selectFile">[Select File]</a>
        <a href="#" id="uploadFile">[Start Upload]</a>

    </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // $(function(){}); not working when data loaded with ajax request
        var ajaxUpload = new plupload.Uploader({

            runtimes: 'gears, html5, flash',
            url: 'upload.php',
            browse_button: 'selectFile',

        });


        ajaxUpload.bind('Init',function(param){
            console.log(param);
            console.log($('selectFile'));
        });

        $('#uploadFile').click(function(){
            alert('Something');
        });

        ajaxUpload.init();


</script>
```

When I append this to the main document, the JavaScript inside it will immediately run and not be able to find the referenced DOM elements.

It works when I add a time-out on the code, but I would like to know a better way at achieving this.

**Update**

Modified to reflect the true intent of the question.

Comment: -1 for lack of basic research - this is the _first_ thing anyone finds in any jQuery tutorial

Comment: @Alnitak , i know you can do that with $(function(){}); but if you see, i say on ajax request, and we can use $(function(){});, i try it but it not worked ...

Comment: @MR.OK - I think this might be the part people are struggling with: `when i load content directly, it work, but when i load it with an ajax request, javascript code will execute but dom elements not ready yet,`. Do you think you can edit your question again and clarify what you mean by this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the manner which you've described, because the JavaScript is not bound to a condition to run, so it runs immediately.

The code inside the document you're receiving via AJAX should be wrapped inside a function by providing side:

```
function onDocumentReady()
{
    // your code here
}
```

Then from the loading code:

```
// get the HTML and JavaScript in data
$('#container').append($(data));
// fire the function to let JavaScript run
onDocumentReady();
```

If you have multiple requests, the providing side should make the `onDocumentReady` function unique by adding random alphabets to the function name, e.g. `onDocumentReady_123()`

Comment: Thanks Alnitak for spotting the typo :)

Comment: what? i say on ajax request, we can't use document.ready on ajax... please read topic

Comment: @MR.OK well, we were all struggling to understand the question ... updated my answer, I think I know what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside a $(document).ready. This will ensure that your JavaScript doesn't run until the DOM is loaded and the elements you're targeting will be available on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ajaxUpload = new plupload.Uploader({

        runtimes: 'gears, html5, flash',
        url: 'upload.php',
        browse_button: 'selectFile',

    });


    ajaxUpload.bind('Init',function(param){
        console.log(param);
        console.log($('selectFile'));
    });

    $('#uploadFile').click(function(){
        alert('Something');
    });

    ajaxUpload.init();
});
```

For more information on how this works, see the documentation for [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). The site also has information on other useful jQuery commands that may be helpful, and I encourage you to check it out and try the examples that are there. Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

If I understand correctly, you're getting something like this HTML from the server:

```
<!-- Pulled HTML from the server using AJAX -->
<div id="uploadForm">
    <div id="fileList">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="selectFile">[Select File]</a>
    <a href="#" id="uploadFile">[Start Upload]</a>
</div>
```

And maybe trying to inject it dynamically into this:

```
<form action=""> <!-- inject HTML here --> </form>
```

If my understanding is correct, then this should allow you to inject the HTML and then only run the JavaScript once the AJAX request completes, and the new DOM has been injected. Keep in mind that, since I don't have all of your code, this is just a conceptual example:

```
$.ajax({ url:"/somepathtoGetData",
    success: function(data) {

        // your HTML is in the variable "data", and this injects the HTML into
          // the form element on the page
        $('form').html( data );

        // now that the DOM elements are loaded from the AJAX request, do your
         // other stuff with the uploader here

        var ajaxUpload = new plupload.Uploader({

            runtimes: 'gears, html5, flash',
            url: 'upload.php',
            browse_button: 'selectFile',

        });


        ajaxUpload.bind('Init',function(param){
            console.log(param);
            console.log($('#selectFile')); // added # for id attr
        });

        $('#uploadFile').click(function(){
            alert('Something');
        });

        ajaxUpload.init();

    }
});
```

Comment: @MR.OK - I'm sorry this did not work for you. If you're not getting the answers you hoped for, then please consider posting debugger output in your question, error messages you're getting. You could also post narrowed-down versions of the code to highlight where you think the problem might be. Also, if you say in your question what you *have* tried already, then people won't suggest things to you that you already know about. Good luck!

Comment: my problem is clear, i want append some html and javascript to my document with ajax request, but first my javascript called and then html append to document

Comment: Are you trying to let your users upload a file? Or are you trying to fetch HTML from the server and load that HTML on your page? Also, check your console statement: I believe you're missing a `#`:  `console.log($('#selectFile'));`

Comment: my problem is not with uploads..., when HTML and JavaScript appended to document, first JavaScript executed , in this time my html not accessible, i can use timeouts and it work but i want find a correct way

Comment: If you can show me what you were doing with the timeouts, I might be able to offer a suggestion, but I would have to see the code to fully understand. You could put that in the body of your question at the bottom. If I understand, you want to avoid timeouts (which is good to avoid) but aren't sure what is a good replacement for timeouts.

Comment: Also, when you say your data is loaded with Ajax, I'm not 100% sure I can picture that either. If you can maybe show an example of what you mean by that in your code, that would really help me understand your problem more clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Say I have two php files, one is main.php, having such codes: (not including jQuery src, please add your own)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#b').click(function(){
            $.post("ajax.php",
            {
                taskaction: "getFormAndJs"              
            },
            function(data){
                        $('body').append(data);
                        // $(document).trigger("ready");
            },
            "text");
            })
    });
</script>

<body>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
    <input type=button id="b" value="click" />
</body>
```

another is ajax.php, like this:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['taskaction'] == 'getFormAndJs') {
    echo '
        <div id="uploadForm">222</div> <input type=button id="a" value="upload" />
        <script>
        $("#a").click(function(){
            alert(123);
        })
        </script>
    ';
}

?>
```

It seems work on my side (click button a and alert "123"), whether I add the

```
$(document).trigger("ready");
```

or not.

Does this look like your situation?

Comment: do you mean you append this form and js to the document by ajax call?

Comment: exactly , i want append all of them with ajax request, and javascript called after html appended

Comment: try $(document).trigger("ready"); at the end of your ajax call